# Can we publish a WORD Add-In to the Windows 10 app store?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, uwp, vsto, windows-10-universal

The `WORD Add-in` is developed using `VSTO` in Visual Studio 2015. It has a custom ribbon with some buttons that perform certain content manipulation of a WORD Document. Can this be converted to a [UWP app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) using, maybe, [Desktop App Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) , [Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop) etc. And then publish that converted UWP app to Windows 10 App Store. **Note**: The converted UWP app does not have to run on all devices - it's ok if it runs only on desktop as a WORD Add-In.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible.
Also the office store accept only web based office add-ins so this is not an option. ( see https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)

Vsto add-ins have to be distributed by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What would you convert using the Desktop App Converter? Word itself? Because that's the application running your add-in, your add-in is not a standalone application. So no, you can't publish to the Windows 10 store.

You can however publish your add-in to the [Office store](https://store.office.com/en-001/appshome.aspx?productgroup=Word). This is a seperate store that people will visit if they try to install an add-in from the browser or from [within Office products](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-an-Office-Add-in-for-Word-d8956c8b-4ae3-4b74-9288-2ee99128a6f1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) itself.

To learn how to publish to the Office store, you can use [this article on Office Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220037.aspx) (MSDN).

Comment: I 'm using VSTO Add-in that can be installed using Windows Installer (a requirement for Desktop App Converter). Ref: see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx). Also, the Office Store accepts only web based Office Add-ins (not [VSTO Add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268878.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we can upload Windows Phone app, Windows Store app and UWP app to the Store. We surely can use Desktop App Converter to publish the desktop app. However, the converter does not support VSTO product for the time being.

You can choose to submit a feature request through the [Windows 10 Feedback hub](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/store/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n). Besides, Office Store currently doesn't support official publish for your VSTO add-in.

Answer (score -1):

Even converted UWP App is running in some container. It has no access to Register or files in system folder nd Program Files. So i'm not sure it'll even work after conversion.

You can try to convert and run your app by yourself. And see if it working.