# Confusion about possibility of publishing a VSTO Add-In to Windows Store or Office Store

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, uwp, vsto, windows-10-universal

We've read conflicting messages about whether or not a `VSTO Add-In` can be published to a [Windows App Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/windows) or an [Office App Store](https://store.office.com/en-001/appshome.aspx?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US). First,

**VSTO Add-in**:

1. It's an application also know as Office Solution. From [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620922.aspx): *You can use the Microsoft Office developer tools in Visual Studio to create .NET Framework applications that extend Office. These applications are also named Office solutions*
2. Also see [Programming VSTO Add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268878.aspx).
3. [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) (i.e, VSTO-AddIn). You can use either `ClickOnce` technology or `Windows Installer`

**Office-Add-in**:

Use web based technology. These Add-ins enable you to extend Office clients such as Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Outlook using **web** technologies like HTML, CSS and JavaScript. [Ref: [Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)]

**Question**: Can someone please clarify the following confusion? In our Stack Overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40372430/1232087) about our `VSTO Add-in` some users seem to indicate that we can upload my VSTO Add-in to `Office App Store` and **not** to Windows App Store. But according to a Microsoft Employee Michael Zlatkovsky in his response to a similar question on an MSDN forum [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c1b6d07-f172-4404-b6e1-028a8ba255f7/can-i-publish-an-excel-addin-to-the-office-app-store?forum=officestore): VSTO add-ins should be able to be listed in the Windows Store as desktop app.

Comment: Michael Zlatkovsky's answer is not correct. See Erik Olson's response in the same thread. Also, please see the answer and comments in this link: [How do I release an Office Add In to the Windows Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465254/how-do-i-release-an-office-add-in-to-the-windows-store/37468904#37468904).

Answer (score 2):

> In our Stack Overflow post  here about our VSTO Add-in, some users seem to indicate that we can upload my VSTO Add-in to Office App Store and not to Windows App Store.

Firstly, Office Store only accept web based office add-in so you're not able to upload your VSTO developed add-in to Office Store for official publishing.

You might refer to [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins).

> But according to a Microsoft Employee Michael Zlatkovsky in his response to a similar question on an MSDN forum  here: VSTO add-ins should be able to be listed in the Windows Store as desktop app.

Please note that the response from @Michael Alatkovsky was from 2013, which is indeed correct at that time. Also, you could refer to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dn322034(vs.85)) provided by him: the content moved, desktop application has been not a part of our new Windows 10 Store. The existing desktop app can still be available to Windows 8.x users but cannot be updated in Dev Center.

However, the [desktop app converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) currently can only enable you to bring your existing desktop apps written for .NET 4.6.1 or Win32 to UWP, VSTO developed app is not supported.

You might submit a feature request through the [Windows 10 Feedback Hub](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/store/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n).

Comment: Would you know if VSTO Add-Ins can now be published to the Windows Store given that MSI and EXE packages can be published as of last year? I could not see any on the store.