# Publishing VSTO Office Add-In on Microsoft Store

Tags: .net, vsto, office-addins, windows-store, excel-dna

I'm interested in finding out whether VSTO Add-Ins (or NetOffice, ExcelDNA, etc.) can be published and sold on the Microsoft Store.

In the past, this was not possible - [reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385767/confusion-about-possibility-of-publishing-a-vsto-add-in-to-windows-store-or-offi).

That said, since then, the model of the Microsoft Store changed.  Now, MSI and EXE packages can be published there.  Then again, I could not find any case-in-point Add-Ins in the store.

Therefore, I'm looking for confirmation whether or not this can be done - alongside any references, examples or personal experiences in doing so.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried and the MSI approach suggested by Eugene seems to work. My Add-In (published just today):

https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/pdftip-visio-addin/XPFD98TZ30SRHB

- It is a VSTO Add-In.
- It is packaged as MSI ("two-modes" MSI, "user" level by default, "all users/admin" as an option for org-wide deployment). This does not matter though, I think, only "user" should be enough.
- Published as "x64" package (although works with x64 and x86 Visio)
- Everything is signed (MSI, EXE)
- There is a "launch" application added to the start menu, to explain the purpose of the app (I was asked to add it, "otherwise the user does not know what to click")

Answer (score 0):

Not quite right - previously it was possible to list your add-in as a Windows desktop application with a reference to the download page on your web site.

There is no publicly available information whether VSTO (COM) add-ins are supported or not. The best way is to try publishing your MSI installer. You may consider it as a regular .net based application.